# Erro "Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 "

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou criando um webservice que terá que pegar alguns arquivos .pdf salvos no banco de dados e enviar para um usuário x.

Para salvar esse arquivo no banco, estou tentando fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
    require("conexao.php");

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];             
    $email = $_POST['email'];   
    $texto = $_POST['texto'];
    $arq_complementar = $_FILES['arquivo_complementar'];    
    $arquivo_complementar = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $arq_complementar);
    print_r($arquivo_complementar);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cartas(nome, email, texto, arq_complementar) VALUES ('$nome', '$email', '$texto', '$arquivo_complementar')";
    $testar_conexao = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

    //header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");
?>
```

Porém o sistema me retorna o seguinte erro: "Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in"

Segue abaixo a forma como estou chamando esse serviço de cadastro

```
<form action="cadastrarMensagem.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Integração</legend>
                <label>Nome:</label> <br>
                    <input type="text" name="nome"> <br>
                <label>Email:</label> <br>
                    <input type="email" name="email"> <br>
                <label>Texto da carta:</label> <br>
                    <textarea name="texto"></textarea> <br>
                <label>Arquivo Complementar:</label>
                    <input name="arquivo_complementar" type="file"> <br> <br>
                <input id="button" type="submit" name="Enviar">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Comment: Acho que a mensagem está bem clara: a função espera uma string como segundo parâmetro e você passou um array. Você pode verificar que é um array a partir do `print_r` que fez. Após corrigir isso provavelmente dará erro de conversão de array para string ao tentar salvar um array no banco. Resumindo, reveja o que fez no código e se condiz com o que queria fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que ocorre é que o $_FILES['arquivo_complementar'] é um array. Se você quer pegar o nome do arquivo enviado, você pode fazer $_FILES['arquivo_complementar']['name']

Aqui tem um link mostrando quais as opções que este array possui:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-_files-array-http-file-upload-variables/

No seu código, não identifiquei a parte onde você salva o arquivo em disco.